# 504 result for Azure web role

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

After publishing my MVC5 app on Azure as a web role it is not accessible.
Fiddler showed me 504 result for root url request.
Instance of web role (it is single instance for now) is accessible by RDP. Endpoint configured by default.

To check that app is starts I put "throw new Exception("XXXXXX")" at the end of Global.asax file "Start" methos before one of publishing try and it returns an error message in browser as it should.

It seems to me that routing configuration is not works. Routiong is default for MVC

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

For azure emulator on local machine all works fine.
Any suggestions? Or might be someone had the same problems?

---

For now I definitely know that error in DB connection.

Error is next

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Source Error:

Line 97:         public IEnumerable GetRecentShapes(int count)
Line 98:         {
Line 99:             return Context.RShapes.Where(s => s.CreationStatus == (int)ECreationStatus.Published).OrderByDescending(s => s.UploadTime).Take(count).ToList();
Line 100:        }
Line 101:

Source File: d:\4_Projects\REPOSITORY\3D\3Dweb\Core\Repository.cs    Line: 99

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]

All I find about this problem - it is happens if connection string is not correct. But it is correct, I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

1. RDP to the Azure VM and browse to the DIP.  This helps narrow down the problem to your app vs. something in the network between your client machine and the Azure VM.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/19/troubleshooting-scenario-5-internal-server-error-500-in-webrole.aspx.
2. Enable Failed Request tracing so you can see what is happening within IIS as the request is being processed.  See http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis  (essentially, just add  to your web.config).
3. RDP to the Azure VM and check the Application event logs to see if any errors are being thrown within w3wp.